# Core Data - Entities or attributes what is more efficient

Tags: swift, attributes

I am new to Core Data and I am struggling to find the correct model for my App which consists of a dictionary builder in several languages. User can enter his own words and traduction in another language or definition in the same language. My core data is setup as following:
One entity: Word with 4 attributes (name, definition, example, option). It works well with one set of entries for instance english words and definition. Now I want to enter a new set of entries or DB which has nothing to do with the previous one. French to Spanish translation. The fields I want to use are the same 4 attributes. How would you update this model to optimise the usage and filtering of words. Two ideas a) I add one attribute dictionary type and need each time to filter on the right dictionary which can be process intensive if I have thousands of entries or b) add an entity? What is the best model for such context?

Comment: name, definition, example, option are the 4 attributes of Word. In the English only set I have a name his definition and example (to learn new words for instance). Now in a 2nd set French to Spanish I will have the French word in name, the translation in definition and an example. Then I can have a 3rd set French-German, etc. In fact several databases to learn words in your language or learn foreign languages and the database are not linked together but uses the same app.

Comment: To be more precise : attribute name is always a name, attribute definition I should change it to "info" as it can be a definition or a just translated word